# Making dropdown lists run function

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have adapted some code from the W3 hoverable dropdown tutorial and want to make it so that rather than following a link when clicked, it passes a value to a function. A rough snippet of the HTML code is below:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Item</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" (change)="selectChange($event)">
        <a value="egg">Egg</a>
        <a value="milk">Milk</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to figure out how to get the value `"egg"` into the JavaScript function `selectChange` if the user clicks on that box, but currently, the boxes are not clickable and don't do anything. I would like to avoid using a `<select>` tag if possible.

Here is the W3 link I got the structure of this code from:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tagged this with angular, so I'm assuming you're using that framework. If that's the case, just use `(click)="function()"`.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Item</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a (click)="selectChange('egg')">Egg</a>
    <a (click)="selectChange('milk')">Milk</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this, it was definitely what I was looking for but I'm still bad with event handling

Answer (score 0):

**Probably the best solution**

How about an eventListener to all the links in the dropdown in Javascript that checks if when a link was clicked and then performs the function with the value of the element that was clicked?

**Probably the easiest solution**

Or maybe for just a few elements or if you don't feel like/don't know how to use an eventListener for this could always use some simple onclick events with a parameter.

```js
function selectChange(selected)
{
  //not sure what you want to do now
  console.log(selected);
  alert(selected);
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content span {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content span:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Item</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <span onclick="selectChange('egg')">Egg</span>
        <span onclick="selectChange('milk')">Milk</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

*In this example a replaced the a-tags with span as you probably shouldn't use an anchor-tag without a href.